Multi-producer, multi-consumer blocking queue
Introduction
This is a queue that allows many producers to simultaneously write their items and many consumers to simultaneously read theirs.  It's useful when construction and/or consumption could be a slow operation.  Strictly speaking, I shouldn't call it a "queue" since it doesn't necessarily preserve order of items, but that's almost meaningless in a multi-producer, multi-consumer scenario anyway.
The interface works by returning a smart pointer which the caller can use as they wish until releasing it, at which point its ownership is returned to the queue.  Typically, producers will ignore the return value from emplace(), meaning this ownership is returned immediately, but they do have the option to hold onto it to manipulate the object before it's enqueued.
Consumers may be able to copy from the queue with auto value = *queue.take(), but they are also entitled to hold on for longer; that's essential if the content is not copyable or moveable.
Implementation
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class buffer
{
    struct value {
        enum class state : char {
            empty, writing, full, reading
        };

        std::optional<T> v = {};
        std::atomic<state> s = state::empty;
        std::condition_variable cv = {};
        std::mutex mutex = {};

        void wait_for_read()
        {
            auto pred = [this]{
                auto expected = state::full;
                return s.compare_exchange_weak(expected, state::reading);
            };
            if (pred()) {
                return;         // uncontested
            }
            std::unique_lock lock{mutex};
            cv.wait(lock, pred);
        }
        void wait_for_write()
        {
            auto pred = [this]{
                auto expected = state::empty;
                return s.compare_exchange_weak(expected, state::writing);
            };
            if (pred()) {
                return;         // uncontested
            }
            std::unique_lock lock{mutex};
            cv.wait(lock, pred);
        }
        void finish_read()
        {
            v.reset();
            std::unique_lock lock{mutex};
            s = state::empty;
            cv.notify_all();    // there may be other readers waiting as well as writers
        }
        void finish_write()
        {
            std::unique_lock lock{mutex};
            s = state::full;
            cv.notify_all();    // there may be other writers waiting as well as readers
        }
    };

    using vector = std::vector<value>;
    using iterator = typename vector::iterator;
    using atomic_iterator = std::atomic<iterator>;

    vector content;
    atomic_iterator next_write;
    atomic_iterator next_read;

public:
    explicit buffer(std::size_t capacity)
        : content(capacity),
          next_write{content.begin()},
          next_read{content.begin()}
    {}

    template< class... Args >
    auto emplace(Args&&... args)
    {
        auto const position = postincrement(next_write);
        position->wait_for_write();
        position->v.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        auto complete = [position](T*){
            position->finish_write();
        };

        return std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(complete)>{&position->v.value(), complete};
    }

    auto take()
    {
        auto const position = postincrement(next_read);
        position->wait_for_read();

        auto complete = [position](T*){
            position->finish_read();
        };

        return std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(complete)>{&position->v.value(), complete};
    }

private:
    // Claim a value of iter, and advance it for next
    // caller, wrapping around at end of content.
    // \param iter a valid iterator into content
    vector::iterator postincrement(atomic_iterator& iter)
    {
        for (;;) {
            iterator before = iter;
            iterator after = std::next(before);
            if (after == content.end()) {
                after = content.begin();
            }
            if (iter.compare_exchange_weak(before, after)) {
                return before;
            }
        }
    }
};

Testing
I did do some testing with immovable and/or uncopiable types, but foolishly discarded those programs.
However, the test I'd really like a review of is my stress-test to ensure that the concurrency works correctly:
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

    buffer<int> buff(2);
    std::atomic<int> sum = 0;

    auto write_value = [&buff](int id){
        auto p = buff.emplace(0);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        *p = id;
    };
    auto consume_value = [&buff,&sum]{
        auto p = buff.take();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        sum += *p;
    };

    // We'll create more than twice as many threads as slots in the
    // buffer.  This means that some slots will have more than one
    // blocked writer or reader.
    constexpr int thread_count = 6;
    constexpr int expected_sum = thread_count * (thread_count + 1) / 2;

    // Stress-test many readers
    sum = 0;
    {
        std::jthread readers[thread_count];
        for (int i = 0;  i < thread_count;  ++i) {
            readers[i] = std::jthread(consume_value);
        }
        for (int i = 0;  i < thread_count;  ++i) {
            write_value(i + 1);
        }
    }
    assert(sum == expected_sum);

    // Stress-test many writers
    sum = 0;
    {
        std::jthread writers[thread_count];
        for (int i = 0;  i < thread_count;  ++i) {
            writers[i] = std::jthread(write_value, i + 1);
        }
        for (int i = 0;  i < thread_count;  ++i) {
            consume_value();
        }
    }
    assert(sum == expected_sum);

    // Stress-test both together
    // This should cause some slots to have both writers and readers
    // waiting.
    sum = 0;
    {
        std::jthread readers[thread_count];
        std::jthread writers[thread_count];
        for (int i = 0;  i < thread_count;  ++i) {
            readers[i] = std::jthread(consume_value);
            writers[i] = std::jthread(write_value, i + 1);
        }
    }
    assert(sum == expected_sum);
}

I modified each test to produce one fewer or consume one fewer and confirmed the expected results (assertion fail when under-consuming, and blocking forever when under-producing).  Is there a better way to test, particularly for the under-production case?
Concerns
I do have reservations about the per-item size overhead (it's particularly noticeable when the data type is int as in the test).  We have a condition variable and associated mutex for each item, which adds quite a lot.  Moving the mutex to the queue itself would reduce that, but at the cost of contention when notifying waiting threads (and notifying without taking the lock would be unsafe here).
Conversely, I could add another condition variable so that writers and readers each queue separately, meaning that we could notify_one() instead of notify_all().  Would that be an improvement?
It's the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the queue outlives its producers and consumers.  Is that reasonable?

I forgot to annotate the // uncontested branches with [[likely]].  That's a minor omission.

Naming issues
There are a few issues with the way you name things:

buffer is too generic; there are all sorts of buffers, but this implements a very specific one. While multi_producer_multi_consumer_blocking_queue is way too long of a name, I would try to condense that somehow. Maybe mpmc_queue? The blocking part is already covered by the names of the blocking member functions.
v, s: definitely avoid one-letter variable names. You can use data instead of v, and ideally s would just be state, which could be done if you start type names with capitals.
cv: this is borderline, but in combination with mutex I think the meaning is clear enough.
postincrement: it does more than just postincrement the iterator, otherwise we'd just write iter++ instead of calling this function. Try to come up with a concise name that would obviate the need for the comments above that function.
vector: I would rename that to data. It's easy to confuse this with std::vector, and we don't care that much about the actual type; if it was a std::array or std::deque the rest of the code would be more or less the same.

Don't mix atomics and mutexes
Mixing atomics and mutexes is almost always a source of bugs, and almost never a performance gain. Inside struct value, either:

Just use a mutex, and in emplace() and take() use mutex.lock() and mutex.unlock() to take and release the item's mutex.
Use std::atomic's own wait() to wait for the state to change.

I strongly recommend using the first method, unless you have actually measured that there is a performance bottleneck and that your solution actually fixes it. Note that std::mutex is very fast in the uncontested case as well, so there is little point in trying to optimize for that, and cv.wait() will first check the condition and return immediately without sleeping if it is satisfied.
next_read and next_write are in a different scope where there's no mutex, so it's fine to keep those as they are.
Don't hold the mutex when calling notify_all()
If you hold the mutex while calling notify_all(), there is a chance that the other threads will wake up, see that the mutex is still locked, and immediately go back to sleep waiting for the thread that called notify_all() to finish unlocking that mutex.
It does preserve the order of items, which can unnecessarily block threads
It seems like you do preserve the order of items in some way: items are taken in the same order as they were actually emplaced in the queue, even though that might not be the order in which buffer::emplace() was called. The point is that if the buffer is full, a writer trying to emplace() is waiting for the oldest reader to finish reading, even though newer readers might already have finished with their work. Consider having many readers, all very quick except for one, and one writer thread, then that writer might get blocked by the slow reader, even though it could have emplaced in other positions in the queue.
The same is true if you have one reader and many writers.

If I don't get the mutex before notifying, isn't there a race condition?  Consider writer W finishing a write while reader R has just entered.  Suppose R examines the state and finds it busy.  Then W sets the state and notifies.  Then R obtains the mutex and waits for notification.  But it's too late now.

R never examines the state without holding the mutex. It always uses a std::lock_guard and then calls cv.wait() with a predicate, which will then do the checking in a thread-safe way.

Somehow I'd convinced myself that the usual practice of notifying after leaving the mutex wouldn't work here.  But I no longer see how I got into that state.

Naming
This looks like some weird combination of memory pool with a thread safe queue. Perhaps separating those two into two classes would make it clearer?
Allocator
It is never used, although there is a template parameter.
Using iterators
Iterators do not lend themselves well to atomic modulo operations. It is much easier to use an index, which can be incremented and the actual index can be extracted with modulo. I do not know number theory sufficiently well, but even if there will be an increment per 1 clock cycle, given current reliable overclock up to 6GHz, it would take ~300 years for the counter to wrap.
No proper lifetime ownership
The rented unique pointers are a lie. If the parent object is pulled from the renter's feet, the whole thing will go up in flames. The object owned by std::unique_ptr is not in fact a unique ownership model, but the holder of the smart pointer plus the parent buffer object. I do not think std::unique_ptr is a good semantical fit here, as smart pointers taught people to use them without much fear.
A new pointer type would have to take std::weak_ptr to the parent object and lock it for any needed operations. Or the parent object could just get a reference counter.

Oh yes, I intended to pass the allocator through into the contained vector, but then forgot to do so.
